# Chain two multiprocessing scripts - python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have two scripts, they are both multiprocessing utilized scripts.

`build.py` reads from a db and spits out a text file. Parallel jobs are launched to do this.

`push.py` inserts/updates this text file to a persistent DB. Again, this is multiprocessing too.

Currently I have two separate crontab commands to do this. I want `build.py` to launch `push.py` then terminate itself, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `subprocess`

In `build.py`

```
import subprocess

def main():
    # Do multiprocessing code, wait for all processes to finish
    ...

    # Launch push.py and exit
    subprocess.Popen(['python', '/path/to/push.py'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Also temporary congrats on being the first to earn the [Bluebook](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5850/bluebook) badge!